# Changing server reference for a Clearcase view

Tags: view, configuration, clearcase

If using the Clearcase Remote client and have a View (View1) created against Server1, is it possible to change the view's configuration so that View1 uses Server2?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily (it would involve a `mktag -view`, which can be done only on CCRC Server2, since [`rcleartool`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929) doesn't include that command).

It is best to create a second view, using server2, with the same config spec as the first view.